# I am getting error Not in Scope error in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghci

Hey it's my first day of haskell journey. I wrote my first program

```
evenOrOdd :: Integral a => a ->[Char]
evenOrOdd n =if div n 2 ==0 then "even" else "odd"
```

And tried the compilation. It succesfully loaded the module, But when i try to call it. It gives me the error N**ot in scope: `evenOrOdd'**
I found a few answers on Stack overflow, But the suggested answers are the exact thing that I have done. Please guide me.
Here is screenshot of terminal
[image]

Comment: It is `Char` not `char`. Likely that i the reason why the module was not loaded.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry it was a typo here on Stackoverflow. I used a capital C in program but the error is same.

Comment: can you share the full console output (including the command you used to load the module)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have edited the question, please take a look

Comment: I cannot reproduce it, works for me.

Comment: @sheldoncooper: are you sure `day1.hs` contains this function (and is saved to the file), and that the module exports this function?

Comment: yes i am sure. The code i typed above, i saved it as day1.hs

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you share your code

Comment: I can't reproduce this error either. It worked fine for me.

Comment: Is that the only code in your entire program? Just those two lines?

Comment: @Chaos_Is_Harmony yes these are the only lines.

Comment: @sheldoncooper, maybe you can try making a ```day1b.hs``` file, copying+pasting those two lines, then compiling+running. When I did that, I had no problem running the code. If that doesn't work, maybe uninstall and then reinstall the compiler.

Comment: You could also try doing `:browse Main` in ghci.  It will list what is in the module.

Comment: As an aside, I am rather shocked to see from your terminal that you are running GHC version 7.6.3 - that's certainly ancient (2013, according to my quick browse of the releases on Github!). It won't cause the problem you have here but you will certainly have problems trying to run code in many tutorials with a compiler version so old - I don't know why you have this if you only started learning Haskell today?